# Linear Algebra: How to prove that $AC^T$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, transpose

How would I prove that the product of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and its adjugate matrix $C^T$ (transpose of cofactor matrix $C$) $AC^T$ is diagonal ($AC^T$=$det(A)I$)? I've attempted to use cofactors and the fact that any non-diagonal element of $AC^T$ is the product of a cofactor and an element that shares a row with the elements of the cofactor, but I don't know where to go from there. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Each entry of $AC^T$ is the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) of the determinant of some matrix. For the off-diagonal entries, this matrix has a repeated row.

Comment: I already thought of that, but I just couldn't think of where to go from there. I could recursively use cofactors until the cofactors were of size 1, and use a sigma sum of size n-1, but I thought that would've been way too complicated

Comment: @catfood Are you aware of the fact that a matrix with a repeated row is singular?

Comment: Ah that. I'm too short sighted and tunnel visioned. Thanks!